# How to get the name of the method in string format

Tags: ruby, string, method-names

I am calling `Some_other_method` inside `Some_method`. I want to pass the name `Some_method` to `Some_other_method` in string format. How can I do it? What should I put instead of question mark as a parameter?

```
def Some_method
  ...
  Some_other_method (?)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Kernel#__method__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__):

> Returns the name of the current method as a Symbol. If called outside of a method, it returns nil.

For example:

```
def say_your_name
  puts __method__.to_s
end
```

You can leave off the `to_s` if you're happy with a symbol instead of a string.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [object#method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001038) for that. From the docs:

Looks up the named method as a receiver in obj, returning a Method object (or raising NameError). The Method object acts as a closure in obj‘s object instance, so instance variables and the value of self remain available.

```
> user = User.first        
=> #<User id: 1, email: "aslam@mapunity.in", created_at: "2011-05-24 07:17:51", updated_at: "2011-06-02 05:28:37", username: "admin"> 

> meth = user.method(:email)    
=> #<Method: User(#<Module:0x9ceff3c>)#_email> 

> meth.name    
=> :email 

> meth.name.to_s
=> "email"
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what is asked. The question is asking to change a method to a string. You are using a symbol/string as a method.

Comment: Right. I agree. Updated the answer to reflect the changes.